# I would like to have the users change the CSS using an optional panel. How should I do this?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I am working on a project in PHP. I would like the users to change colors,font-size,etc on their profile using an options panel. Something similar to WordPress theme optional panel.

Can someone point me into the right direction to how I should go about doing this?

Comment: take a look at jsfiddle.net you can embed this in your site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create admin panel where a user can enter in their style settings.
2. Write your php code to take the data from that form, and save it to where ever you are storing data.
3. When the pages load that these styles will be applied on, use javascript to set the styles.  For example, if you're using jQuery on your site, and you were going to apply a text color to all the text on the site, you'd do this:

   // Assume that the variable customColor has been set with the data from your database.
   $('p').css('color', customColor);

Now if you haven't done much javascript, or much interaction between a script and your server side php, there are probably gaps here.

Comment: your answer coupled w/ LonelyWebCrawler helped me figure out how to do this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create an options panel on your site that is a form submitting to a PHP file. In that PHP file, make sure that the data the user submitted is valid, then use a `mysql_query()` to  update this data in the user's MySQL row. Of course, you need to set up your MySQL (or other database) structure beforehand so that every user profile has fields like `font-size` or `color` associated with it.

When you display your website to a logged in user, use another `mysql_query()` to see what the user's preferences are. Then use PHP to echo out the user's preferred HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Write a PHP script that accepts a userid as a parameter, and outputs a CSS file with all the user's settings. Then have all your other scripts do something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="user_style.php?id=<?php echo $userid; ?>">
```